# In SOLR DB when I execute query I have data, but when I'm trying to do that in code, I have array with empty data

Tags: c#, solr

I'm trying to get back data from SOLR DB (trought query in code).
I can reach through data with http directly in DB.

This is my query :

`http://.../select?indent=on&q=*:*&sfield=Geo&pt=45.15,14.85&sort=geodist()%20asc&fl=_dist_:geodist()&wt=json`

```
var spatial = new LocalParams { { "type", "geofilt" }, { "pt", coordinates[0].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "," + coordinates[1].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) }, { "sfield", "Geo" }, { "d", distance } , { "sort", "geodist() asc" }, { "fl","_dist_:geodist()} + new SolrQuery("");
queryOptions.FilterQueries = new[] { spatial };
var datax = ops.Query(new SolrQuery($"-externalid:{sd.ID}"), queryOptions);
```

I expect the output like :

```
"_dist_":0.09629470319718479}
```

Comment: You can check the Solr log to see exactly what query was sent to the server - turn logging up to the `INFO` level and it'll show you what the server received - and you can then compare it to what you're sending manually. That being said, I can't see any `fq` in your query url above, while you're trying to set it in the code?

Comment: @MatsLindh Its done, problem was here in query
{ "sort", "geodist() asc" }, { "fl","_dist_:geodist()} instead, I added one more line in queryOptions - fields

var queryOptions = new QueryOptions
   {
    Rows = sd.PageSize,
                Fields = new[] { "*", $"_dist_:geodist(Geo,{coordinates[0].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)},{coordinates[1].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}) asc" }
            };